# Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR for string matching b/w two columns

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, join

**The problem**

Users are frequently inputting "country name" strings into the "city name" field. Heuristically, this appears to be an extremely common practice. For example, a user might put "TAIPEI TAIWAN" in the city name when only "TAIPEI" should be input and then the country would be "TAIWAN". I am working to aggregate these instances for this specific field (your help will allow me to expand this to other columns and tables) and then identify where possible rankings associated with strictly the "country" names in the "city" field.

I have two tables that I am attempting to leverage to track down data validation issues. Tbl1 is named "Customer_Address" comprised of geographic columns like (Customer_Num, Address, City_Name, State, Country_Code, Zipcode). Tbl2 named "HR_Countries" is clean table of 2-digit ISO country codes with their corresponding name values (Lebanon, Taiwan, China, Syria, Russia, Ukraine, etc) and some other fields not presently used.

The initial step is to query "Customer_Address" to find City_Names LIKE a series of OR statements (LIKE '%CHINA', OR LIKE 'TAIWAN', OR etc etc) and count the number of occurrences where the City_Name is like the designated country_name string I passed it and the results are pretty good. I've coded in some exclusions to deal with things like "Lebanon, OH" so my overall results are satisfactory for the first phase.

Part of the query does a LEFT join from Tbl1 to Tbl2 to add the risk rating from tbl2 as a result of the query against tbl1:

```
LEFT JOIN tbl2 risk 
 ON INSTR(addr.CITY_NM, risk.COUNTRY_NAME,1) <> 0
```

### Example of Tbl1 Data Output (head(tbl1), n=7)

```
CountryNameInCity   CountOfOccurences   RR
China             15                     High
Taiwan                 2000                  Medium 
Japan              250                   Low
Taipei, Taiwan     25                    NULL
Kabul, Afghanistan  10                   NULL
Shenzen China   100                  NULL
Afghanistan          52                       Very High
```

### Example of Tb2 Data (head(tbl2), n=6)

```
CountryName CountryCode RR
China   CN          High
Taiwan  TW          High
Iraq    IQ          Very High
Cuba    CU          Medium
Lebanon LB          Very High
Greece  GR          High
```

So my question(s) are as follows:

1) Instead of manually passing in a series of OR-statements for country codes is there a better way to using Tbl2 as the matching "LIKE" driving the query?

2) Can you recommend a better way of comparing the output of the query (see Tbl1 example) and ensuring that multiple strings (Taipei, Taiwan, etc) are appropriately aggregated *and* bring back the correct 'RR' rating.

Thanks for taking the time to review this and respond.

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but why are you comparing city with country?  Why not outer join tbl2.country_code to tbl1.country_code? What "validation" issues are you trying to uncover?

Comment: The validation is that there is none on the current system -- so it's more of an aggregation of the control failures. Users are putting country names in the city name, hence the query against city_nm as opposed to country_cd.